# How to write a recursive query with 2 tables in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query, dynamicquery

I have a table with the following structure.
Table name: Table0

The structure is as below

```
Select process from Table0 where Name like '%Aswini%'

Process
-------
112
778
756
```

All these process must go into the below table
Table name: Table1

The structure is as below

```
Select Exec, stepid, condition 
from Table1 
where Exec = 112

Exec   stepid condition
-----------------------
112     2233     0
112     2354     0
445     3455     0
```

The second table 'Table 2' structure follows:

```
Select stepid, processid  
from Table2 
where stepid = 2233

Stepid processid
-----------------
2233      445
2354      566
3455      556
```

The Table1 `stepid` is input to Table2 `stepid` and Table2 `Processid` is input to Table1 `Exec`. I have to recursively get `processID` until the condition is 0 else the table returns no rows and the final processid is the parent ID.

I have not worked on CTE. So I have used a simple join to get the following result.

```
select b.processid 
from Table1 a 
inner join Table2 b on a.stepid = b.stepid 
where a.condition = 0 
  and a.exec = 112(parent from table0)
```

The above query will give me parent of Exec 112 if it satisfies the condition.

I have to again input the parent to the query and execute it.

I can achieve this with the help of C# by putting it in a loop. But I want it in SQL Server alone. Is this achievable?

Edited

When I execute the CTE I get the below result

```
Process Parent
  112     445
  112     566
  112     445
  112     566
```

If the initial process has 2 exec then the final process parent structure is duplicated twice( number of exec). Why is this happening. It has to display the result only once.

Comment: You can achieve this by creating a function in Sql-server.

Answer (score 3):

A solution without a cursor (which I personally prefer):

```
WITH [CTE] AS
(
    SELECT
        T1.[Exec] AS [process],
        1 AS [n],
        T1.[Exec],
        T1.[Exec] AS [parent]
    FROM
        [Table1] AS T1
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        C.[process],
        C.[n] + 1,
        T1.[Exec],
        T2.[processid]
    FROM
        [CTE] AS C
        INNER JOIN [Table1] AS T1 ON T1.[Exec] = C.[parent]
        INNER JOIN [Table2] AS T2 ON T2.[stepid] = T1.[stepid]
)
SELECT C.[process], C.[parent]
FROM [CTE] AS C
WHERE C.[n] = (SELECT MAX([n]) FROM [CTE] WHERE [process] = C.[process])
```

Explanation:

The anchor part of the common table expression (the `SELECT` query before the `UNION ALL`) defines the starting point of the operation. In this case, it simply selects all data from `Table1` and it has four fields:

- `process` will contain the value of the process (`Exec` value) of which the parent should be determined.
- `n` will contain a sequence number, starting with 1.
- `Exec` will contain a "shifting" value for joining records in the next "recursive" part of the common table expression.
- `parent` will contain the corresponding `processid` field from `Table2`, which represents the direct parent of the `Exec` value.

This anchor expression will produce the following data:

```
process      n      Exec      parent
112          1      112       112
445          1      445       445
```

The recursive part of the common table expression (the `SELECT` query after the `UNION ALL`) keeps adding records to the CTE from `Table1` (where its `Exec` value equals the `parent` value of the previous CTE record) and `Table2` (related with `Table1` on the `stepid` fields). Those newly added records in the CTE will have the following field values:

- `process` will be copied from the previous CTE record.
- `n` will be increased by 1.
- `Exec` will get the `Exec` value of the joined `Table1`'s `Exec` value (equal to the previous CTE record's `parent` value).
- `parent` will - again - get the corresponding `processid` value from `Table2` where its `stepid` value equals `Table1`'s `stepid` value.

The entire CTE will yield the following results:

```
process      n      Exec      parent
112          1      112       112
112          2      112       445
112          3      445       556
445          1      445       445
445          2      445       556
```

The main query (below the CTE) will select only the `process` and `parent` fields for each "last" record in the CTE (where the value of `n` is the largest value for that specific `process` value, which is determined using a subquery).

This produces the following end result:

```
process      parent
445          556
112          556
```

Hope this helps a little.

**Edit regarding the update in the question regarding 3rd table `Table0`:**

Assuming that your query `SELECT [process] FROM [Table0] WHERE [Name] LIKE '%Aswini%'` will contain valid processes for the query above to return, only the WHERE-clause of the main query above needs to be changed.

Previous WHERE-clause:

```
WHERE C.[n] = (SELECT MAX([n]) FROM [CTE] WHERE [process] = C.[process])
```

Updated WHERE-clause:

```
WHERE
    C.[n] = (SELECT MAX([n]) FROM [CTE] WHERE [process] = C.[process]) AND
    C.[process] IN (SELECT [process] FROM [Table0] WHERE [Name] LIKE '%Aswini%')
```

**Edit regarding possible duplicates when processes have more than one parent**

In case a process has more than one parent (??), the above query produces duplicates. To eliminate the duplicates and to provide a more robust way for determining the topmost parent of a process, the following modifications were made:

1. The anchor part of the CTE puts the actual parent of a process in the `parent` field by joining `Table1` to `Table2`. This join should be a left join, so that processes without parents (if possible) will be included in the results too; their `parent` value will be equal to their own process id.
2. The recursive part of the CTE should only add parents for processes that have an actual parent (where field `process` is not equal to `parent`). This is to avoid infinite loops in recursivity (if possible).
3. The main query should filter out all records where the value of the `parent` field is also used in another result record as the value of the `exec` field for the same base process (the value in the `process` field). Because in that case, the `parent` field is not the final parent value, and that other result record might be a more fitting candidate for containing the actual parent.
   In other words: if process A has parent B, and process B has parent C, there are three related results in the CTE: (A, A, B), (A, B, C), and (B, B, C). Result (A, A, B) is invalid, because a more fitting candidate (A, B, C) is available in the results too. The final results should include (A, C) and (B, C), but not (A, B).
   This logic is implemented using a subquery in an EXISTS operator in the WHERE clause, but it could also be realized using a LEFT JOIN on the CTE itself as well, of course.
4. Because of the upgraded logic described in point 3, the column `n` of the CTE is not used anymore and has been removed.
5. To avoid duplicates in case of a "diamond pattern" in the data (process A has parents B and C, and both processes B and C have parent D), a DISTINCT is used in the main query's SELECT clause to avoid duplicates (A, D).

The final query would look like this:

```
WITH [CTE] AS
(
    SELECT
        T1.[exec] AS [process],
        T1.[exec],
        COALESCE(T2.[processid], T1.[exec]) AS [parent]
    FROM
        [Table1] AS T1
        LEFT JOIN [Table2] AS T2 ON T2.[stepid] = T1.[stepid] 
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        C.[process],
        T1.[exec],
        T2.[processid]
    FROM
        [CTE] AS C
        INNER JOIN [Table1] AS T1 ON T1.[exec] = C.[parent]
        INNER JOIN [Table2] AS T2 ON T2.[stepid] = T1.[stepid]
    WHERE
        C.[parent] <> C.[process]
)
SELECT DISTINCT C.[process], C.[parent]
FROM [CTE] AS C
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [CTE]
                WHERE [process] = C.[process] AND [exec] = C.[parent])
    AND C.[process] IN (SELECT [process] FROM [Table0] WHERE [name] LIKE '%Aswini%')
```

I hope this works well enough for you.

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you provided an explanation regarding how the code works.

Comment: Okay. I will add some explanations.

Comment: wow. it works as I wanted. I have additional use case. What if Exec value is coming from a different table. Will the CTE work for 3 tables.ex query: select process from table 0 where name like '%Aswini%'

Comment: I have edited my question. can you tell me if 3 table recursion is possible
?

Comment: OK. I looked at the updated question. Looks like the relation between Table1 and Table2 remains the same, so the query probably needs no structural update. Table0 seems to be a new table containing the "Aswini-processes". Is it correct that the query should now only show processes from Table1 that are also contained in Table0?

Comment: I added an edit-section at the end of my answer. Can you please check if it is what you expect?

Comment: I get duplicate processes. for ex: if a process has more than 1 exec the result will look like for 2 exec under 1 process:

process 112 112 112 112                   
                                                                                                                Parent    234 667 234 667

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue regarding duplicates, but I did not succeed. Can you please add an extra section to your question for this scenario and provide the new data in `Table1` and `Table2` that yield your duplicate results?

Comment: I have edited my question and I hv provided the result your query is yielding. can you please provide a solution for this

Comment: I have looked at your edits and have reproduced the issue. I am looking into it, but it seems my answer has some serious flaws. I will continue to work on it and provide a corrected answer as soon as possible. But even when your scenario is logically correct, it is very confusing though... (Suppose A relates to B and B relates to both C and D, then both A and B have parents C and D, correct?)

Comment: I have thought about it some more. Seems your data structure will not be hierarchical (like trees), but networked (like directed graphs). Suppose A relates to B and to C. And both B and C relate to D. Then A, B and C have all parent D. And if D relates back to A again, none of them have an absolute parent, because you have cyclic relations. Finding a solution in SQL will perhaps be possible, but I will have to give this one up. Perhaps you should completely rephrase your question and include all possible logical scenarios to get a fitting answer.

Comment: Thanks for the try. I can do it in normal joins within loops but it affects performance. that is why I wanted in CTE. Your query works perfectly but its producing duplicates. else I would have used it .

Comment: Do you have any solution for this using cursor. How will be the performance if its used

Comment: I can eliminate the duplicates from my query, but that is no guarantee that the query will be correct. When I started my answer, I did not expect a single process to have multiple parents. (Multiple processes having the same parent is logical, but the other way around is not. IMHO.) Investigating and providing a correct solution begins with a complete understanding of the actual problem and a description of all valid scenarios. Being confronted with this kind of "breaking changes" afterwards is frustrating and unnecessary. That's why I "gave up" on this question.

Comment: I could build an example using a cursor too. But that solution would suffer from the same issues as with the CTE. If the problem is not completely known, the solution might not suffice. I don't know about performance differences. All I can say about cursor-based operations, is that they indeed have a (much) lesser performance than set-based operations. That's why I would not want to investigate such a cursor-based solution when I also have a set-based solution. The only reason for me to fall back to a cursor-based solution is having an issue that cannot be solved with set-based operations.

Comment: How do we eliminate duplicates from the query. If I get this I can check on the feasibility

Comment: I am already creating an edit to my answer to provide you the query variant that eliminates the duplicates. I will also include a short explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try using a cursor and storing the first table in cursor and get the process id by going till the end of the cursor.

```
DECLARE f_cursor CURSOR FOR     
Select Exec, stepid
from Table1

OPEN f_cursor    

FETCH NEXT FROM f_cursor     
INTO @exec,@stepid
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0    
BEGIN
select b.processid 
from Table1 a 
inner join Table2 b on a.stepid = b.stepid 
where a.condition = 0 
  and a.exec =@exec
//store the processid somewhere for later use.
END     
CLOSE f_cursor;    
DEALLOCATE f_cursor;
```

Comment: I am getting an error , must declare a scalar variable "@exec" in this step ' and a.exec =@exec'

Comment: Below is my Query   
    DECLARE f_cursor CURSOR FOR     
Select Process
from table0

OPEN f_cursor    

FETCH NEXT FROM f_cursor     
INTO @Process
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0    
BEGIN
select b.processid 
from Table1 a 
inner join Table2 b on a.StepID = b.StepID 
where a.Condition = 0 
  and a.exec =@ProcessID
END     
CLOSE f_cursor;    
DEALLOCATE f_cursor;

Comment: then declare a variable with exec and stepid